# Separating AJAX requests and success callbacks in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've defined a function that will capture mouse clicks on links with a `data-remote` tag as follows.

```
// Global AJAX request handler
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'a[data-remote]', function(event) {
        var target = $(event.target);
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        var method = $(this).data('method');
        $.ajax(url, {type: method, data: $(this).data()})
            .done(function(data){
                target.trigger('complete', data);
            })
            .fail(function(data) {
                target.trigger('failure', data);
            });
    });
});
```

The function captures `done` and `fail` events and then proceeds to trigger a new custom event (`complete` or `failure`) on the element that was initially clicked to start the whole thing off.

Elsewhere, it's now possible to do something like...

```
$('#list').on('complete', 'a[data-remote]', function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

...to hide the element that was clicked, providing that the AJAX call was a success.

It feels like capturing an event and immediately triggering a new one is a bit convoluted. Does jQuery provide an easier way to do this? I've looked around the `ajaxSuccess` event...

```
$('#list').on('ajaxSuccess', 'a[data-remote]', function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

...but it doesn't trigger. Is there an obvious reason why?

Comment: `$(document)` can be used. Not other usual elements.

Comment: declare a variable outside your click() function and assign the ajax function to it, so you have it at the document scope, then you should be able to easily access the right callback each time.